# Add a click event to the bar chart of chartjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, chart.js

Is it possible to identify the exact segment that is clicked on in a bar chart? I've three "bars" in the chart. When I click on a particular bar, I'm calling the getBarsAtEvent() to see which particular portion of the bar is called. But getBarsAtEvent() is returning an array of all the data points in that bar. I need to know which exact portion is clicked. Is there anyway to achieve this?

Answer (score -1):

Try using the event parameter.  Every function called by your webpage has an event object as the last parameter.

You can read more about the event object [here](http://javascript.info/tutorial/obtaining-event-object)

I suspect you would use something like `event.target` to get the specific node you clicked on.